# What time of year do STEM professors typically work on grant proposals?

Tags: funding

What time of year do STEM professors typically work on grant proposals?

Is it always between semesters, e.g. the summer months?

Comment: Easier to identify when they don't - it is a much shorter list...

Comment: Working on the project or writing a new grant application?

Comment: This is highly country-dependent. In some countries grant deadlines are spread across the entire year while in other countries they can be concentrated in a specific part of the year (in some cases October-November).

Comment: Whenever they have time, if they're anything like us non-professor PIs. :/

Comment: Please specify the country in question.

Answer (score 8):

Throughout the year. At least in the U.S., timings are driven in part by when funding agency deadlines are. For most NIH  grants, there are [three submission windows](https://grants.nih.gov/grants/how-to-apply-application-guide/due-dates-and-submission-policies/due-dates.htm) per year. For NSF, there are one or two, but when these occur is different for different programs. Plus, in general, thinking about funding is a major task, and can't be confined to a brief span of time.